# Why does setting NSWindow.titleVisibility = .Hidden cause window to grow 22 points each launch?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, macos, cocoa

I've tracked this issue to: `window!.titleVisibility = .Hidden`

When removing the title, the NSWindow size will grow 22 points in height with each launch, with Autosave enabled too. How can I avoid this, but still remove the title?

Answer (score 0):

You need set window size in applicationDidFinishLaunching so is it will grow then not same thing happen in next launch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden;